# setAdvertiseMode in android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder not mocked

Tags: unit-testing, bluetooth, mocking, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-testing

I am writing Junit test cases using mockito for myclass
it is using jUnt mockit with the help of junit4

```
 InternalBluetoothManager @Inject constructor(
    private var context: Context,
    private var rxBleClient: RxBleClient
) : BluetoothGattCallback() {

private val advertiserSettings: AdvertiseSettings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
        .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
        .setConnectable(false)
        .build()
}
```

**this is where I am writing Junit test cases for InternalBluetoothManager class but it is giving me this error and i am not allowed to use powermock**

```
iseMode in android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setAdvertiseMode in android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
```

**here is the test class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class InternalBluetoothManagerTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockRxBleClient: RxBleClientMock

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockBluetoothManager: BluetoothManager

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockBluetoothAdvertiser: BluetoothLeAdvertiser

    private lateinit var mockInternalBluetoothManager: InternalBluetoothManager

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockHandlerThread: HandlerThread

    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockHandler: Handler


    @Mock
    private lateinit var mockLooper: Looper

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this@InternalBluetoothManagerTest)
    }

    @Test
    fun testSetup(){
        println("Testing Started")
        val mockSettings=mock(AdvertiseSettings::class.java)
        var mockSettingsBuilder= mock(AdvertiseSettings.Builder()::class.java)
        whenever(mockSettings.mode).thenReturn(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        whenever(mockSettingsBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(anyInt())).thenReturn(mockSettingsBuilder)
//       whenever(AdvertiseSettings.Builder().setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)).thenReturn(mockSettingsBuilder)
        mockInternalBluetoothManager=InternalBluetoothManager(context,mockRxBleClient)
        println(mockInternalBluetoothManager.bluetoothStatus())
    }
}
```

**here is the stacktrace for the error**

```
Method setAdvertiseMode in android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setAdvertiseMode in android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder not mocked. See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/not-mocked for details.
    at android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings$Builder.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.java)
    at com.systems.trackonomy.rightone.data.bluetooth.InternalBluetoothManager.<init>(InternalBluetoothManager.kt:53)
    at com.systems.trackonomy.rightone.data.bluetooth.InternalBluetoothManagerTest.testSetup(InternalBluetoothManagerTest.kt:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```